# Luabind - Unable to find Lua library

Tags: lua, luabind

I am trying to compile Luabind for my project with little success. I have the lua directory (containing src, the makefile etc) as a sibling of luabind. I have LUA_PATH set to the /my/dirs/lua folder. I am running OSX Server 10.4.

When I go into luabind and type bjam i get the error:

```
error: at Jamroot:101
error: *** Unable to find Lua Library
```

If I set LUA_PATH to an *incorrect* directory the error is at line 73 (Unable to determine Lua include directory).

I have loosely followed this tutorial: http://cfc.kizzx2.com/index.php/building-luabind-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem as you.

Im running Mageia 3.

Inside the Jamroot I noticed that it used `local lib = $(prefix)/lib ;` to specify the path. 
In my machine, the path where LUA was installed is `/lib64`. I changed and it worked.

Check the file and see if it correspond with your system. I noticed that not only the path was hardcoded, but the LUA library version as well.

Yeah, I know your system use MAC and that this post is from 2012.. I just hope this answer can help anyone that end up with this, or similar problem.